# How to prevent class qualification when using nested enum class in member function arguments

Tags: c++11

Consider a nested enum class, which is passed as argument to a member function of that class.

```
class VerboseClassName {
public:
    enum class Unit {KG, TON};

    void foo(Unit unit) { /*...*/ }
};
```

Using this type of construction always feels kinda awkward to me, as the class name has to be qualified even from within the method call.

```
void bar() {
    VerboseClassName a;
    a.foo(VerboseClassName::Unit::KG);
}
```

Would it make sense to consider the class scope available in calls to the classes members? Is there a technical reason why this would lead to trouble?

Comment: Enumerators of an scoped enumeration defined in the class are *not* members of the class. (AFAIK that's why these enumeration types are called _scoped_ enumeration.)

Comment: Chicken and egg: you would need to know what class (if any) the function belongs to in order to look up the names used in function arguments; but you also need to know the types of function arguments in order to look up function name (what with argument-dependent lookup and overload resolution) and figure out which class  (if any) the function is a member of.